# hybris with idea "build project" failed

Tags: intellij-idea, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

When I try to build(build->build project) Hybris project with Idea, it fails and tells me that it can't remove `projectcore\hmc\bin\projectnamecorehmc.jar` or `projectnameserviceshmc.jar`.

I'm removing this **.jars** manually, and it works, but getting annoying to do it almost every time when I need rebuild project.

Also with ant project builds without any problems.

Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem before. I don't remember what exactly I did to resolve it. It might be because the file Ant tried to delete was a part of a classpath for another task.

### You can give a try

- Try running your console/Ant script as an administrative user, using Run As.
- Create the new workspace for your IDE
- Make sure you are using the same version(32 bit or 64 bit) for your ANT and JDK. If that is the case uninstall your JDK and install the right version.
- Upgrade your IDE to latest version

Comment: @Evgenii - did you get the solution?

Comment: I tried to do this, but it's not helped. I'm maybe missing something, but ide build not using ant, right?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure Hybris is not running when you rebuild it with IntelliJ ; this may cause this kind of errors.

Comment: it's not running for sure, because in this case, it won't be able to rebuild project at all if I remember right because of models.jar